# Looking for best bootstrap tab plug-in which replicates browser tabbing system

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently I am using Jquery [easyUI tab](https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tabs.php)

Unfortunately it is not supporting the responsive design and didn't have control over the close action.

My requirement is replication of browser tab system inside of the application with control over close button.

Does anyone have used any other plug-in? Googled it but didn't found the solution what I was looking.

Comment: Voted to close as: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @vvr02 i think did you try the build in tabs from bootstrap ?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs